# Why does initializing a sigint variable with memset() help prevent Seg Faults?

Tags: c++, c, struct

**BACKGROUND:**

struct sigaction is used to set up the handlers for a small C program that handles interrupts. The issue arose when I received a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error message after completing implementation of the second handler. I set up both handlers exactly the same way. The first interrupt handler worked fine without initializing the sigaction struct, however, I received the seg fault error when I finished implementing the second handler.

**QUESTION:**

Why does initializing the sigaction struct with memset() help fix the error?

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ALARMSECONDS    3
int numSigints = 5;

/* Handler function that prints out the current time on a SIGALRM interrupt. */
static void hdl(int signum)
{
    time_t currTime;
    time(&currTime);
    printf("\ncurrent time is %s", ctime(&currTime));
    alarm(ALARMSECONDS);//re-arm the alarm

}

/* Handler function that captures SIGINT interrupts 5 times before 
   actually exiting. Makes use of global variable to keep track of
   number of times the interrupt was sent.
 */
static void sigint_hdl(int signum)
{

    numSigints -= 1;    

    if(numSigints == 0)
    {
      printf("\nFinal Control-c caught. Exiting.\n");
      exit(1);
    } 
    else
    {
      printf("\nControl-c caught. %d more before program is ended.\n", 
        numSigints);
    }   
}

/* Periodically prints out the current time in Unix date format using 
   sigaction interrupt handling.   
*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    //
    // vars
    //
    struct sigaction act;
    struct sigaction sigint_act;

    memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));//TODO Why does this fix SEGFAULT???

    //
    // intro
    //
    printf("Date will be printed every 3 seconds.\n");
    printf("Enter ^C 5 times to end the program.\n");

    //
    // set alarm to go off in 3 seconds
    //
    alarm(ALARMSECONDS);

    //
    // set handler of the sigaction to 'hdl' function defined above
    //
    act.sa_handler = hdl;
    sigint_act.sa_handler = sigint_hdl;

    //
    // activate sigaction
    //
    if(sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL) < 0)
    {
      perror("sigaction -- SIGALRM");
      return 1;
    }

    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &sigint_act, NULL) < 0)
    {
      perror("sigaction -- SIGINT");
      return 1;
    }

    //
    // infinite loop
    //
    while(1) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is uninitialized, just like any other variable would be if you declared it like that.

Comment: Without the memset you are passing uninitialized variables to `sigaction`.

Comment: Also, C++ is not C.  There are other ways to initialize a struct's members to 0 if you're using C++ (other than calling `memset`).

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I suspected it had something to do with uninitialized variables, but I wanted to know why it still worked the first time with an uninitialized variable. And yes, C++ is not C, but the question is still relevant.

Comment: @bale If it's C++, then using the brace initialization syntax would have also set the members to 0 `sigaction act = { };`.

Comment: `= { 0 };` works in both language

Comment: @bale -- The comment section is for comments, so I commented.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Me too. Also the question isn't asking about syntax. M.M, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of fields in the `sigaction` structure. Making them all zeroes sets them to their default values.

If they are not zeroes, they will be interpreted in whatever way is described in the system call's documentation. One example would be two fields `sa_mask` and `sa_sigaction`. and depending on the values of `sa_mask`, the `sa_sigaction` handler will be invoked instead of your intended signal handler, that your code installs. And since you did not initialize the pointer, it will have some garbage value, and an attempt will be made not to merely dereference, but invoke a function through a garbage pointer.

So, if you fail to initialize the structure, you get undefined behavior. Sometimes it'll work, sometimes it won't in mysterious ways, such as a crash.

By clearing the entire structure to zeroes, you are assuring that the default behavior will take place, as modified by any non-default settings you them make to the structure.

Lesson learned: always clear and initialize all structures that are passed to library functions.

Comment: can `sa_flags` be non-zero by default (i.e., when we do not explicitly say `sa.sa_flags = 0;`) ? Does doing `memset...` set `sa_flags` to `0` the same as `sa.sa_flags=0;` does?

Comment: Nothing is "by default", by itself, in C or C++. Everything must be explicitly initialized, one way or another.